# Issue in accessing HDFS file inside spark map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My use case requires to access the file stored in HDFS from inside the spark map function. ThIs use case uses custom input format that does not provide any data to the map function whereas the map function obtains the input split and access the data. I am using the below code to do this

```
val hConf: Configuration = sc.hadoopConfiguration
hConf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getName) 
hConf.set("fs.file.impl",    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
var job = new Job(hConf)           
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path("hdfs:///user/bala/MyBinaryFile"));


    var hRDD = new NewHadoopRDD(sc, classOf[RandomAccessInputFormat], 
        classOf[IntWritable], 
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        job.getConfiguration() 
        )    

    val count = hRDD.mapPartitionsWithInputSplit{ (split, iter) => myfuncPart(split, iter)}.collect()
```

As of now, I am not doing anything inside the myfuncPart. This simple returns a map as below

```
 iter.map { tpl ⇒ (tpl._1, tpl._2.getCapacity) }
```

When i submit the job along with the dependencies, I get the below error

```
15/10/30 11:11:39 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 40.221.94.235): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: spark
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
```

At first glance, it seems a small error related to spark jars but could not crack. Any  help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a mistake from my side with the way I was launching the job. The command I was using did not have proper option in it. Hence, the issue. I was using the command below

```
spark-submit  --class org.myclass --jars myjar spark://myhost:7077 myjob.jar
```

Below is the correct one

```
spark-submit  --class org.myclass --jars myjar --master spark://myhost:7077 myjob.jar
```

This is a small mistake but somehow I missed it. Now it is working