# Spark - Map transformation

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Why does Map transformation take single line as single element?

If I create RDD from an external dataset such as text file, it takes single line as single element?

Is there any way to change this so that it will match a pattern instead default single line?

or

Should I use other transformation like filter?

If I should use other transformation, why can't we do it in Map?

Please help me.

**Example:**

My file contains

> A map is a transformation operation in Apache Spark which is applied
>   to each element of RDD and it returns the result as new RDD. In the
>   Map operation developer can define his own custom business logic; the
>   same logic will be applied to all the elements of RDD. Map function
>   takes one element as input process it according to custom code
>   (specified by the developer) and returns one element at a time. Map
>   transforms an RDD of length N into another RDD of length N. The input
>   and output RDDs will typically have the same number of records.

Then map process

element one as [A map is a transformation operation in Apache Spark which is applied to each element of RDD]

Is there any way with map so that I can take [A map is a transformation operation in Apache Spark which is applied to each element of RDD and it returns the result as new RDD.] as single line. [dot pattern matching]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your first question :
Its not that `map` function is taking `single line` at a time. `map` function is just `transforming` the `RDD` (Resilient Distributed Dataset) to other `RDD` form. Its the `sparkContext` or `sqlContext` or `Source` library that is reading the text files line by line. 
Each of the `contexts` are using `TextInputFormat` class that `Hadoop` has been using originally. And that `TextInputFormat` class `parses` the input file by line using (`\r or \n`) delimiter, reading text files line by line. 
Now
If you want custom reading format as you've mentioned in your question to read lines by delimiting by `foolstop`(`.`), then you will have to write custom `inputFormat` class and tell the `contexts` to use your `custom inputFormat` class.
I hope the answer is clear

**Edited**

[Ingesting data with Spark using a custom Hadoop FileInputFormat](https://www.ae.be/blog-en/ingesting-data-spark-using-custom-hadoop-fileinputformat/) and [Custom Input Format in Hadoop](https://acadgild.com/blog/custom-input-format-hadoop/) and [simple image format converter](https://hadoopinku.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/simple-image-format-converter/) and [Using Custom Hadoop input format for processing binary file in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373898/using-custom-hadoop-input-format-for-processing-binary-file-in-spark) should give you a good start to work on custom `inputFormat`

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. If you add some links to refer more, it would be really helpfull

Comment: @GopsAB, I have updated some links for a quick start ups.